# I'm getting a None, with every line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was coding a small program, and when I run it I get a None. Here goes an example:

```
    print('Welcome to CTFTOOL')
    print('Created by P.R.B.')
    print('Choose your option:')
    inp1 = input(print('''
    1)Auto Caesar Chiper.
    2)Binary-Decimal & Decimal-Binary.'''))
```

After the fourth print I get a None, and this with every print that asks for an input.

```
    if inp1 == '1':
        text1 = input(print('Input the text you want to decode:\n'))
        autocaesarchiper(text1)
```

Here I get another None before the autocaesarchipher() function runs.
I've been looking to another code that works well, but I haven't seen the problem yet.
Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks all, now is working correctly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20function#input) takes an arguement and prints it out before taking the input.

The none is what you are seeing after the `print()` function fires off. In python if your functions don't return anything and is done it returns None by default. For example:

```
print(print())
```

outputs:

```
     #new line
None
```

To fix your code just do:

```
text1 = input('Input the text you want to decode:\n')
```

Answer (score 5):

`input` will print a message for you. Don't pass the actual `print` function to it.

```
inp1 = input('''
    1)Auto Caesar Chiper.
    2)Binary-Decimal & Decimal-Binary.''')
```

The `print` function's return value is where the `None` is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

The `print()` inside your `input()` function is returning `None`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```
def g(a,b):
 print(a+b)
```

is kind of equivalent to:

```
def g(a,b):
 print(a+b)
 return None
```

So if you call `print(g(1,2))` This will perform the action of the inner function, but will also output its return value, `None` in this case

Generally, if you place a function call inside another function call you get `None`, if the function does not return anything. For example, `function(function())` outputs `None`.

So does `input(print())` or `print(print())`. Be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test():
    print('Welcome to CTFTOOL')
    print('Created by P.R.B.')
    print('Choose your option:')
    inp1 = input('Choose one: \n (1)Auto Caesar Chiper. \n 2)Binary-Decimal & Decimal-Binary.')
    if inp1 == 1:
        text1 = input('Input the text you want to decode:\n')
        autocaesarchiper(text1)
print(test())
```